# To print only the first occurence of a substring in c

Tags: c, substring

I am new to C. I have a code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int i = 0;
int main()
{
    char text[] = "..... $it is beautiful : $yes you are correct....";
    char * sub = "$";
    char * ret = strstr(text, sub);

    if (ret != NULL)
    {
         printf("the statement is : %s", ret);
    }
}
```

I  would like to print only this part of the code: `$it is beautiful`.
 Is there any way to print only that statement? Let us assume that this a part of a full body text, so any idea other than using the `strlen` ?
The print should not occur when the second `$` appears.This is the basic requirement for me

Comment: What print are you getting now?

Comment: $it is beautiful : $yes you are correct....     this is the print output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int i=0;
 int main()
{
    char text[] = "..... $it is beautiful : $yes you are correct....";
    char* sub = "$";
    char* ret = strstr(text,sub);
    char *out = malloc(strlen(text)+1); //To make the solution generic

    if (ret!=NULL )
     {
         sscanf(ret, "$%[^$^:]", out);
         printf("the statement is : [%s] \n",out );
     }

     free(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strchr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchrnul.3.html) with `:` or `$` as per your output requirement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char text[] = "..... $it is beautiful : $yes you are correct....";
    char * ret = strstr(text, "$");
    if (ret != NULL) {
        char *colon;
        if (colon = strrchr(ret, ':'))
            *colon = '\0';
        printf("The statement is: %s", ret);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> The statement is: $it is beautiful